# Explicit call to parameterized constructor throws an Error

Tags: c++, constructor

While creating object we can have implicit or explicit call to constructor

```
Base obj;
Base obj = Base(1,2);
```

Both these object creation methods are working fine, until I include copy constructor in code.
Here is the code snippet.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Base {
    public:
    Base(int x, int y) {}
    Base() {}
    Base(Base& o){}
    private:
    int a;
    int b;
};

int main() {
    Base obj = Base(10,20);    /*This line throws error after including copy Ctor*/
    Base obj2 = obj;
}
```

I am using Linux g++ compiler. 
Error : no matching function for call to ‘Base::Base(Base)’

Am I missing something.

Comment: Did you remove relevant code or does your copy constructor really not initialize anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copy Constructor should be of following form, to enable the temporary object creation with `Base(10,20)`

```
Base(const Base& o){}
 //  ~~~~ notice `const`
```

Alternatively, you can use move constructor with C++11, to allow temporary objects

```
Base(Base &&o){}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was missing const in this.

Answer (score 2):

You have two possibilities. Either change the declaration of the copy constructor like

```
Base( const Base &o){}
```

Or add a move constructor

```
Base(Base &&o){}
```

For example

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Base {
    public:
    Base(int x, int y) {}
    Base() {}
    Base(Base& o){}
    Base( Base && ){}
    private:
    int a;
    int b;
};

int main() {
    Base obj = Base(10,20);    /*This line throws error after including copy Ctor*/
    Base obj2 = obj;
}
```

The problem with your code is that expression `Base(10,20)` creates a temporary object that can be binded only with a constant reference.

in fact you need not to define the copy constructor explicitly for this simple class.